# Unable to delete HDFS Missing/Corrupt files

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

I am unable to delete corrupt files present in my HDFS.

when i launch :

```
hdfs fsck -list-corruptfileblocks
```

i got some blocks corrupted : `The filesystem under path '/' has 10 CORRUPT files`

```
hdfs dfs -rm /path/to/filename.fileextension

rm: `/path/to/filename.fileextension': No such file or directory
```

I also tried

`hdfs fsck / -delete`

```
  Under-replicated blocks:       0 (0.0 %)
     Mis-replicated blocks:         0 (0.0 %)
     Default replication factor:    3     
     Corrupt blocks:                0
     Missing replicas:              0 (0.0 %)   
    The filesystem under path '/' is HEALTHY
```

I've also restart both of namenodes and the bug still occurs

Can anyone please help me in this case ? 
Here is a similar [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47278453/unable-to-delete-hdfs-corrupt-files?noredirect=1#comment90155916_51595087) :

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. `hdfs fsck / -delete` returned 0 Corrupt blocks, which seems to be the thing you were trying to do in the first place. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Exactly, it's confused for me too. The files doesn't exist anymore (that's why not found) but the hdfs fsck -list-corruptfileblocks still list them !

Comment: Try to run `hdfs dfsadmin -metasave <filename>` and check the output of this command. Does it show any corrupted blocks?

Comment: Nothing : 

Metasave: Blocks waiting for replication: 0
Mis-replicated blocks that have been postponed:
Metasave: Blocks being replicated: 0
Metasave: Blocks 0 waiting deletion from 0 datanodes.
Corrupt Blocks:

Comment: So no need to worry. Ignore the error. Your cluster is healthy.

Comment: I know it is, but I want to delete those warnings. Thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score 1):

maybe the corrupt files are in snapshot, and you should delete snapshot

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsSnapshots.html